# Is it possible to export swagger interactive api Documentation as static html to put into Confluence?

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I have a Spring Boot project and I have an API documentation automatically created with swagger. With the following dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

It looks very nice so i am curious if I can export it somehow as html (but with css to have the nice look) to use it in Confluence.

I did already try to do it via `https://editor.swagger.io/` and pasted my swagger json in there, but the export as html, html2 or dynamichtml looks terrible.

Is there a way to get the same interactive swagger api documentation as in the project.

Comment: If you mean the UI to be interactive once you host it on a page in Confluence, I'm not sure if that's something supported. As far as automating the way you've tried you can use the [Swagger-Codegen Maven Plugin](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) along with the [OpenAPI Generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of exporting the swagger UI I would reference in an iframe. Use the confluence html macro for that like this

[image]

Alternatively you can download the page with a website downloader e.g.: https://www.httrack.com/ . It will download all CSS, javascript etc. Once you have the files you should copy to a webserver and reference from your iframe in confluence.

If you don't have a webserver then a hackier solution is to download the swagger page as a single HTML using

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/singlefile/mpiodijhokgodhhofbcjdecpffjipkle

Then attach the file to confluence and include this iframe :

```
<iframe id="result" style="width: 100%; height: 100vh;border:none;" 
scrolling="no"></iframe>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
 method: 'GET',
 url: '/download/attachments/...',
 dataType: 'text',
 success: function(data) {
 var iframe = document.getElementById('result');
iframe = iframe.contentWindow || ( iframe.contentDocument.document || iframe.contentDocument);

iframe.document.open();
iframe.document.write(data);
iframe.document.close();
 }
});
});
</script>
```

make sure to change the /download/attachments/... to the actual download url where the download button points to

[image]

See solution here :

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Confluence-questions/HTML-file-as-attachment/qaq-p/641523#M86102

Comment: Unfortunately the project will be discontinued so this is no possibility.

Comment: that is trickier, I updated the answer accordingly

Comment: Good morning, this works partially, i am able to download the file, but after downloading the site is not interactive anymore. So I opened all the expandables and downloaded it, so at least I can see everything. After changing scrolling to yes I can scroll, but it is not interactive. Is there maybe a way to make it interactive?

Comment: look at your browser's developer console to see it there is an error

Comment: Look into the console while downloading with SingleFile?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it with Swagger, but Swagger's json can be exported to `Redoc` **static html** quite easily:

```
yarn global add redoc-cli
redoc-cli build http://localhost:5000/swagger/v1/swagger.json
```